# Redirect (302) between endpoints of controller in Blazor WebAssembly Hosted project using IFlurlClient

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I am dealing with an issue regarding redirecting in server controller in hosted Blazor WebAssembly project.

As an example, I [modified](https://github.com/GodEmperorOfTime/FlurlWasmRedirect/blob/master/BlazorWasm/Server/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs) default `WeatherForecastController` to redirect one endpoint to another.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
  return Redirect("WeatherForecast/redirected");
}

[HttpGet("redirected")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetRedirected()
{
    // default implementation returning some random WeatherForecasts
}
```

In the client, there are two [implementations](https://github.com/GodEmperorOfTime/FlurlWasmRedirect/blob/master/BlazorWasm/Client/IWeatherForecastClient.cs) of service, which requests said endpoint. First one makes request using regular `HttpClient`, second with `IFlurlClient`.

```cs
class HttpWeatherForecastClient : IWeatherForecastClient
{

  readonly HttpClient httpClient;

   // constructor and stuff

  public async Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastsAsync()
  {
    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast")
      ?? Array.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
  }
}

class FlurlWeatherForecastClient : IWeatherForecastClient
{
  readonly IFlurlClient flurlClient;

  // constructor and stuff
  public async Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastsAsync()
  {
    var response = await flurlClient.Request("WeatherForecast").GetAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"{response.StatusCode}: {response.ResponseMessage}");
    return await response.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>()
      ?? Array.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
  }
}
```

Implementation with `HttpClient` works fine. Implementation with `IFlurClient` keep returning response with  *ReasonPhrase* `opaqueredirect` and *StatusCode* with value `0`.

Is there way to configure `IFlurClient` to work with redirection?

I tried to [implement](https://github.com/GodEmperorOfTime/FlurlWasmRedirect/blob/master/BlazorWasm/Client/AluPerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory.cs) custom `IFlurlClientFactory` to modify configuration of `IFlurlClient`. But I have no idea which option I need to change :(

```cs
public class AluPerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory : PerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory
{
  protected override IFlurlClient Create(Url url)
  {
    return base
      .Create(url)
      .WithAutoRedirect(true)          
    ;
  }
}
```

If there is something relevant in [documentation](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#redirects), I don't get it.

Example project: https://github.com/GodEmperorOfTime/FlurlWasmRedirect/

## Edit - possible solution

Based on the answer provided by Todd Menier, I think a reasonable solution is to register `IFlurlClient` like [this](https://github.com/GodEmperorOfTime/FlurlWasmRedirect/blob/solution/BlazorWasm/Client/Program.cs):

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(services => {
  return new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) };
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFlurlClient>(services => {
  var httpClient = services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
  return new FlurlClient(httpClient);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you're getting is clearly originating from the [client-side `fetch()` operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type) that is ultimately handling the call:

> `opaqueredirect`: The fetch request was made with `redirect: "manual"`. The Response's status is 0, headers are empty, body is null and trailer is empty.

I believe at some point WASM is using a [custom (and, sadly, internal) handler](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/main/src/runtime/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpHandler.cs) to somehow ensure that the `fetch()` request uses `"follow"` instead of `"manual"` for that [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect).

Fortunately there's a simpler option here than trying to reverse-engineer this to work the same way with Flurl: just allow WASM to provide the `HttpClient` (as in your example that actually works), but within your service class, create a `FlurlClient` that wraps it:

```cs
class FlurlWeatherForecastClient : IWeatherForecastClient
{
  readonly IFlurlClient _flurlClient;

  public FlurlWeatherForecastClient(HttpClient httpClient)
  {
    _flurlClient = new FlurlClient(httpClient);
  }

  public async Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastsAsync()
  {
    // use _flurlClient here
  }
}
```

Now you can use a `FlurlClient` that defers its work to the injected `HttpClient`, which in turn defers its work to that handler we don't have direct access to. Although I've not tried this, my expectation is it should just work, and you shouldn't even have to care about those underlying details.